# Stronger result than bertrand's postulate

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

It is well known that there is a prime number between $n$ and $2n$ for all $n$. I decided to go deeper: is there a lower bound on the number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ for "large enough" $n$?

For instance, I found empirically that $\pi(n)-\pi(n/2)\ge \sqrt n$ at around $n\ge 100$ (In particular, I also used a program to show $\pi(n^2)-\pi(n^2/2)\ge n$ for $n\ge 10$). Does there exist a nice elementary proof of this?

Obviously, we can show this result asymptotically for very great $n$. I ask to consider an elementary proof of the above bound.

Comment: For any $k > 1$, there is at least 1 primes between $n$ and $kn$ for large enough $n$. This means that for all $N$, there are at least $N$ primes between $n$ and $2n$ for large enough $n$.  (EG Set $k^N < 2$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your reply. However I'm interested in looking at a provable bound on $n$ for that to be true, and not simply "large enough". Again thanks for yours time.

Comment: How did you use a program to show something for (all) $n \ge 10$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Theorem 1.2 and 1.3 of [Axlar's 2017 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08032.pdf), we have for  $x \ge 49$,

$$
\pi(x) < \frac{x}{\ln x - 1 - \frac{1}{\ln x} - \frac{3.15}{\ln^2 x} - \frac{12.85}{\ln^3 x} - \frac{71.3}{\ln^4 x} - \frac{463.2275}{\ln^5 x} - \frac{4584}{\ln^6 x} }
$$

and for $x \ge 19,033,744,403$,
$$
\pi(x) > \frac{x}{\ln x - 1 - \frac{1}{\ln x} - \frac{2.85}{\ln^2 x} - \frac{13.15}{\ln^3 x} - \frac{70.7}{\ln^4 x} - \frac{458.7275}{\ln^5 x} - \frac{3428.7225}{\ln^6 x} }
$$

Plug in these inequalities you will get the best currently known bounds on $\pi(n) - \pi(n/2)$.

Another way to look at a stronger form of Bertrand's postulate is found in Theorem 3.6 of [Das and Paul's 2019 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09891.pdf) where they proved that

> *For any integer $n$ and $k$, if $n \ge 1.1\ln(2.5k)$, there are at least $k-1$ primes between $n$ and $kn$.*

Both of these are relatively new results so I don't think much has been improved since their publication.